# Understanding Kruskal-Katona Theorem and lower shadows

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, optimization, extremal-combinatorics

I am reading the following paper :
I. Balla, B. Bollobas, T. Eccles, Union-closed families of sets, Journal of
Combinatorial Theory Series A, 120 (2013) 531-544.

In the second Theorem, the authors mention Kruskal-Katona Theorem and say that:
"The fundamental theorem of Kruskal and Katona states that if $\mathcal A\subseteq\mathbb{N}^{(k)}$ with $|\mathcal A|=m$. then the lower shadow of $\mathcal A$ is at least as large as the lower shadow of $\mathcal I_{k}(m)$; consequently, $|\partial^i(\mathcal A)|\geq |\partial^i(\mathcal I_{m})|$ for all $\mathcal A\subseteq\mathbb{N}^{(k)}$ with $|\mathcal A|=m$ and $0\leq i\leq k$."

Here, $\mathcal I_k(m)$ is the set of intial segment of length $m$ of $\mathbb{N}^{(k)}$ in colex order.
I have a couple of questions here:

1. What is the meaning of $\partial^i(\mathcal A)$? From what I could find online, lower shadow of a set $A$ is $\partial(A)=\{A-\{i\}:i\in [n]\}$ and lower shadow of a family is union of lower shadows of all the members. But what is  $\partial^i(\mathcal A)$?
2. On the wikipedia page of the Kruskal Katona theorem, the statement of the theorem is given as:
   " An integral vector $(f_0, f_1, ..., f_{d-1})$ is the $f$-vector of some $(d-1)$-dimensional simplicial complex if and only if

: $ 0 \leq f_{i} \leq f_{i-1}^{(i)},\quad 1\leq i\leq d-1.$"

This, at a first glance and a few glances after that, looks far away from the statement provided in the paper. Are these two equivalent?

Comment: Maybe $\partial^i=\partial\circ\cdots\circ\partial$ (with $i$ $\partial$s)?

Comment: What's $I_m$? Is  it the set of the first $m$ elements of $\Bbb N^{(k)}$ in the colex order?

Comment: @AnginaSeng From the definition that you have provided, does the given inequality follow $(|\partial^i\mathcal A|\geq|\partial^i(\mathcal I_k(m)|$)? For $i=2$, applying Kruskal-Katona to $\partial^2\mathcal A$, we get that $|\partial^2\mathcal A|\geq|\partial(\mathcal I_k(|\partial A|)|$. Is there a way to conclude from here?

Comment: @AnginaSeng Yep that is the definition of $\mathcal I(m)$. I have added it to the question.

Comment: What you mention in 2. is not the statement of the K-K theorem, it is just a fact/definition stated as an introduction to the theorem. The actual theorem is about f-numbers and comes later. And it is the same, it just counts the number of faces in the shadow.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek : Oh, I see. My bad. I will correct the question.